# close hidden div onclick and toggle another div

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, hidden

i am using the following code to toggle hidden divs.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);

          $(e).slideToggle("slow");




    }

<div id="toplinks">
<a href="../index.php">Home</a> | <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('aboutus');">About Us</a> | <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('contact');" >Contact us</a> | <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('social');">Social Media</a> | <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('contact');">Send your demo</a> | <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('presskit');">Press Kit</a>
</div><!--toplinks end -->
```

the problem is that if i click on all of them, the would all appear in the page at the same time.
is there a way to close automatically one (if its open), so that only one div appears if clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your prev id in variable, and if it not null, make toggle again. For example:

```
var prevId;

function toggle_visibility(id) {
   if(prevId && id !== prevId){
      $("#"+prevId).slideToggle("slow");
   }
   var e = document.getElementById(id);

      $(e).slideToggle("slow");
   prevId = id;

}
```

Comment: is there a way to implement this code, so that the open div, if clicked again, closes, instead of toggling again???thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes.

first of all, add `panel` css class to **each** of the panels that suppose to appear and disappear with navigation items click.

secondly, add css class to **each** `<a>` tag with it's name (home, aboutus, etc...)

and then use this jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#toplinks a').click(function(){
        $('.panel').hide(); // hide all panels
        if ($(this).hasClass('home')) {
            $('.panel.home').fadeIn(); // show homepage panel
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('aboutus')) {
            $('.panel.aboutus').fadeIn(); // show about us panel
        }
        // more items ...
    });
});
```

hope that helped.